# importlib.reload() not reloading file into ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-importlib

I have a ipython notebook running in Jupyter Lab. It is running a function that uses variables from an external module I made called "Myfile.py".

`Myfile.py` includes a few variables that are initially defined like so:

```
Myterms = ['honda accord', 'ferrari', 'mazerati', 'dodge dumpster']
```

I have made a few edits to the `Myterms` list in `Myfile.py` and then saved the changes to the file.

```
Myterms = ['Nissan Leaf', 'Tesla Roadster']
```

What I want to do is reload the `Myterms` list from `Myfile.py` into the notebook so that when I call the variables in the list they reflect the changes that have been made.

I've been using a version of code from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module) :

```
import myfile
import importlib

def reloader(myfile):
    importlib.reload(myfile)
    from myfile import Myterms

reloader(myfile)

print(Myterms)
```

But the line `print(myterms)` still prints out

```
['honda accord', 'ferrari', 'mazerati', 'dodge dumpster']
```

UPDATE: For some reason, the old `Myterms` list seems to be hanging around in memory and is not being overwritten despite the `importlib.reload` function. After doing some more research [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/438845/9525212) may offer some clues as to why, but I can't find a workaround.

Comment: With the code you've posted, `searchterms` would be a module, not a list.

Comment: I just changed the module name to make things a little clearer.

Comment: Haven't you tried `myfile = importlib.reload(myfile)`?

Comment: I just did. It didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are looking for: **Autoreload** available in IPython.

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2

In [3]: from foo import some_function

In [4]: some_function()
Out[4]: 42

In [5]: # open foo.py in an editor and change some_function to return 43

In [6]: some_function()
Out[6]: 43
```

source : [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)